# Knockout's mapping breaks observable arrays

Tags: knockout.js, observer-pattern, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm experiencing a strange problem with Knockout's mapping plug-in.

If I fill an observable array through mapping I can't iterate the array or get its length, even though the UI is updated correctly, the array seems empty.

You can find a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VsbsC/

This is the HTML mark-up:

```html
<p><input data-bind="click: load" type="button" value="Load" /></p>
<p><input data-bind="click: check" type="button" value="Check" /></p>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p data-bind="text: total"></p>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.load = function () {
        self.items([
            { "name": "joey", "value": 1 },
            { "name": "anne", "value": 2 },
            { "name": "paul", "value": 3 },
            { "name": "mike", "value": 4 }
        ]);
    };
    self.check = function () {
        alert(self.items().length);
    };
    self.total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
            total += self.items()[i].value;
        }
        return total;
    });
};
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When I click on the *Load* button both the records and the total are displayed correctly, and when I click the *Check* button I get the correct item number.

However, if I change

```js
self.items([
    { "name": "joey", "value": 1 },
    { "name": "anne", "value": 2 },
    { "name": "paul", "value": 3 },
    { "name": "mike", "value": 4 }
]);
```

to

```js
self.items(ko.mapping.fromJS([
    { "name": "joey", "value": 1 },
    { "name": "anne", "value": 2 },
    { "name": "paul", "value": 3 },
    { "name": "mike", "value": 4 }
]));
```

the UI still get rendered correctly, but the total shows zero, clicking *Check* yields zero too, and `console.info`-ing `self.items` yields an empty array.

How is this possible? I've re-read the tutorials countless times, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

P.s. I need to fill the observable array through the mapping plug-in because in the real page the values are coming from an AJAX request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is based on the fact that the mapping plugin will create an observableArray if it is given an array.  So, you are setting the value of the `self.items` observableArray equal to an observableArray (rather than just an array).  So, it is wrapped an extra time.

Here is one way to do it:

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    self.load = function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS([
            { "name": "joey", "value": 1 },
            { "name": "anne", "value": 2 },
            { "name": "paul", "value": 3 },
            { "name": "mike", "value": 4 }
        ], self.items);
    };
    self.check = function () {
        alert(self.items().length);
    };
    self.total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0, items = self.items();
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += items[i].value();
        }
        return total;
    });
};
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

So, you initialize the original observableArray using the mapping plugin, so it is ready to be updated.  Then, on the update you call `ko.mapping.fromJS` with the updated data and the the mapped object to update.

The other minor change at that point was just to use `value()` in your computed observable now that it is an observable from the mapping plugin.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3La5K/

Comment: You code works perfectly. The problem lies in `self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);`: during my tests before the question I do have tried what you wrote, but I initialized the property with `self.items = ko.observableArray();`, and it doesn't work that way. As I'm unable to find anything in [mapping's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/297) to request to add an explanation.

Comment: Yes, your UI is already bound to the original observableArray, so when you update it with your data you want to make sure that you are able to update the original array and not replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try [knockout-data-projections](https://knockoutprojections.codeplex.com/)

It hanldes view model to js arrays mappings quite well!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `items` `observableArray` to the mapping function so that it can map the new values into it.

Working solution here:
http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/j9pdX/

```
self.load = function () {
    ko.mapping.fromJS([
        { "name": "joey", "value": 1 },
        { "name": "anne", "value": 2 },
        { "name": "paul", "value": 3 },
        { "name": "mike", "value": 4 }
    ], {}, self.items);
};
```