# KnockoutJS observable array - how to get length

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a KnockoutJS model which has observable arrays, that I need to be able to both load from JSON, and also add to by simply pushing data objects to the array. I am finding that when I load data using mapping, I can no longer get the length/count of items in an array, it is always equal to zero. I think this is due to the mapping?

Here is the ghist:

```
var SalesPerson = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data != null) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {Regions: regionMapping, Customers: customerMapping},     self); 
    } else {
        self.ID = ko.observable();
        self.FullName = ko.observable().extend({
            required: {
                message: '* Persons name needed'
            }
        });
        //self.Regions = ko.observableArray(); 
         self.Regions = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
         self.Customers = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
         //self.Customers = ko.observableArray(); // array of "Customers", who each     have many orders
    }
```

Note I originally was putting in the array using eg `self.Regions = ko.observableArray();`, then changed to this `self.Regions = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);` after seeing a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035673/knockouts-mapping-breaks-observable-arrays)

Here is a fiddle of the entire:  [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qtime67/kgkE7/)

To test the fiddle, click "Load from in-line model" .. the "count" of regions and customers should update but it does not, it stays at zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An observable is a function, so you have to call it before accessing any property.

So it should be `text:Regions().length` not `text:Regions.length`

Here's updated [version](http://jsfiddle.net/kgkE7/1/)

Comment: details details ... I'll get the hang of it all yet, many thanks!

Comment: I really don't understand why I keep getting "Regions is not a function". But if I do console log then it prints out a function